# Rails/Rspec - How to use multiple it without redoing work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Multiple times I want to check multiple things over the same action, say that I want to do a PUT and see if the request returned 200 and if the response value contains some values and if the `ActiveRecord` model was updated.

From the next example I tried using `before` but it runs just before each `it`.

```rb
context "with valid params" do
  before do
    put my_url
  end

  it "returns a 200 response" do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end

  it "updates the right values" do
    expect(my_model.min_area).to eq(111)
    expect(my_model.max_area).to eq(222)
  end

  it "dont update a param if it is not sent" do
    expect(my_model.budget).to eq(333)
  end
end
```

I want the `before` block to run just 1 time, and each it verify it's things.
With this approach I can see clearly what failed when it fails.

Other way to do it will be removing each `it` and just have 1 like:

```rb
context "with valid params" do
  it "updates all" do
    put my_url

    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    expect(my_model.min_area).to eq(111)
    expect(my_model.max_area).to eq(222)
    expect(my_model.budget).to eq(333)
  end
end
```

But this approach does not tell me immediately what failed when it fails.

How can I do this without having to do the `before` for each `it` block?

Comment: If you are accessing outside services, and your main goal is performance/efficiency, you could also consider using a gem like `vcr` which first records and then "replays" the answer in later occurences. This would allow to write your tests as before and still benefit from a performance gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `before(:context)` you might do this

```
context "with valid params" do
  it "updates all" do
    put my_url

    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    expect(my_model.min_area).to eq(111)
    expect(my_model.max_area).to eq(222)
    expect(my_model.budget).to eq(333)
  end
end
```

But what you need is to tell RSpec to [aggregate failures](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:aggregate_failures)

You can do [it per block](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures#use-%60:aggregate-failures%60-metadata)

```
context "with valid params", :aggregate_failures do
  it "updates all" do
    put my_url

    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    expect(my_model.min_area).to eq(111)
    expect(my_model.max_area).to eq(222)
    expect(my_model.budget).to eq(333)
  end
end
```

Or set it [globally for your project](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures#enable-failure-aggregation-globally-using-%60define-derived-metadata%60), and other options are available, choose what fancy you most.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`before(:context)`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-%60before(:context)%60-block-in-example-group).

```
before(:context) do
  put my_url
end

context "with valid params" do
  it "returns a 200 response" do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end

  it "updates the right values" do
    expect(my_model.min_area).to eq(111)
    expect(my_model.max_area).to eq(222)
  end

  it "dont update a param if it is not sent" do
    expect(my_model.budget).to eq(333)
  end
end
```

Please note that some might argue that using `before(:context)` is an [anti-pattern](https://rspec.rubystyle.guide/#avoid-hooks-with-context-scope).

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this aproach is deprecated, it was removed from `rspec 3` and also I can't access `let` from there... I still don't get why